# Official statistics of each season

Tags: hearthstone

Are there any official sources and statistics from Blizzard about

- How many players have reached the Legend rank each season?
- Which class performed best/worst? (Most wins, Most losses, Win/Lost versus other classes)
- Most played card?
- Card that finished off the opponent? Etc.

There are some sites that provide some stats but they rely on the players that have to provide the information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry, but Blizzard does not release regular general statistics about Hearthstone. [Daily Dot has an article](http://www.dailydot.com/esports/hearthstone-stats-secret/) positing that Blizzard intentionally keeps theses statistics a secret.

However, they do occasionally release a variety of non-regular statistics. For example:

- In "[Hearthstone Chat - You're Better Than You Think](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/blog/15955974/hearthside-chat-youre-better-than-you-think-9-18-2014)"

  - Indicated the percentage of players that reach different rankings in ranked play.
- In an info-graphic shared in "[Hearthstone Chat - Mobile Development Update](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/blog/16421347/hearthside-chat-mobile-development-update-10-21-2014)"

  - Number of players that have played.
  - Most played heroes.
  - Hounds unleashed, bananas eaten, etc.
- Every month they release a [final rankings sheet](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/blog/18555824/hearthstone%C2%AE-march-2015-ranked-play-season-final-rankings-4-7-2015) for the highest ranking players.

  - No statistics represented.

In essence, your best bet to find official statistics on Hearthstone is to regularly check the [news section at Battle.Net Hearthstone](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/blog/) and hope they post the statistics you would like to see.

Comment: The first link definitely sums it all up. Thanks for sharing.